# Fitting a waveform to a set of points and choosing discrete intervals from it

Tags: r, curve-fitting, waveform, spline, wavelet

I have a data.frame of values with samples taken at intervals that were not exact hours. The samples form oscillating waves of unknown amplitude and period. I would like to estimate the value at every exact hour.

```
      hours value
60 63.06667 22657
61 64.00000 21535
62 64.93333 20797
63 65.86667 20687
64 66.80000 20129
65 67.73333 19671
66 68.66667 19066
67 69.60000 19534
68 70.53333 19994
69 71.46667 19575
70 72.40000 21466
```

Is there a way in R I can fit a curve to this data set, and then sample it at my given points (63,64,65,66...)? I'm aware of `spline()` but don't know how to make it give me exact integer values for 'hours'.

Edit: To clarify, this is the resulting data frame I wish to have (with dummy entries for 'value')

```
   hours value
63.00000 22800
64.00000 21535
65.00000 20780
66.00000 20500
67.00000 20011
68.00000 ...
69.00000 ...
70.00000 ...
71.00000 ...
72.00000 ...
73.00000 ...
```

Code to recreate data:

```
structure(list(hours = c(63.06666647, 63.9999998, 64.93333313, 
65.86666646, 66.79999979, 67.73333312, 68.66666645, 69.59999978, 
70.53333311, 71.46666644, 72.39999977), value = c(22657L, 21535L, 
20797L, 20687L, 20129L, 19671L, 19066L, 19534L, 19994L, 19575L, 
21466L)), .Names = c("hours", "value"), row.names = 60:70, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with  Sean's answer,  but use the `splinefun` tool to create your own interpolation function.  Run the function thus created on a vector of your hour values to calculate the interpolated values at those exact values.  The examples given on the `?splinefun` page are pretty clear.

Comment: Commenting on myself :-) -- If you ever get interested in fitting to a set of sine functions (you did say your data were periodic), take a look at the eureqa application from Cornell.  (not an R function--it's a standalone application)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up with

my.function <- splinefun(D$hours, D$value)
my.function(63:73)

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach with the spline fit might be:

```
D <- structure(list(hours = c(63.06666647, 63.9999998, 64.93333313, 
65.86666646, 66.79999979, 67.73333312, 68.66666645, 69.59999978, 
70.53333311, 71.46666644, 72.39999977), value = c(22657L, 21535L, 
20797L, 20687L, 20129L, 19671L, 19066L, 19534L, 19994L, 19575L, 
21466L)), .Names = c("hours", "value"), row.names = 60:70, class = "data.frame")

sm <- smooth.spline(D$hours, D$value, spar = 0.5)
```

Or whatever smoothing factor for `spar` you prefer

```
plot(D$hours, D$value)
lines(sm, col = "red")
```

You can access the fitted y-values for each hours from the smooth spline by

```
sm$y
[1] 22421.54 21682.93 21023.05 20469.70 19998.72 19634.10 19448.09 19506.52 19783.97
[10] 20251.24 20891.14
```

Comment: Unfortunately this simply gives me a smoother line. Type sm$x and you'll see that I have no value at exactly 65.00... or 66.00... - this is my requirement.